# Https page doing Http request using CORS

Tags: http, https, cors

Reading the [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#user-agent-security) it states *[abridged]*:

> ... user agents are allowed to terminate the algorithm and not
>   make a request. This could be done because e.g.:
>
> ...
>
> - https to http is not allowed.
>
> ...

This appears to be the behavior in Chrome, however I have not found any reference to this behavior on the various browser vendors documentation.

For performance reasons we wish to make an http request from a https page for certain content. It is a request to a different domain entirely with the correct CORS headers to do http requests (which work ok http->http).

Are there any headers that can be set to allow https -> http? It seems sensible to disallow mixed-mode on a single domain / sub-domains, but cross-domain seems over protective, especially if the other domain allows http normally.

I'm imagining the '[preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#resource-preflight-requests) check' or a 'simple request' would be allowed if it didn't have [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers or alike.